# Error en java: "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final"

Tags: java, variables, timer

estoy constuyendo una aplicacion que usando el codigo Morse, convertido a ceros y unos, me devuelva un JPanel con colores, emulando una linterna y su tiempo de luz.

En general todo funciona bien, pero a la hora de meter el proceso en un timer, me genera este error: **"local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final"** dentro de la funcion del Timertask.

```
public void msj(String txtC) {
    int j=0;
    char[] Mensaje;
    Mensaje = txtC.toCharArray();
    j= Mensaje.length;


            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run(){

                decision(Mensaje, j);
                if(Mensaje.length == j)
                {
                    timer.cancel();
                }

               }
            };
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
            timer.cancel();
 }
```

He intentado hacen funciones "globales" pero no hay forma de que las variables trabajen dentro del Timertask. Aqui dejo el resto del codigo, muchas gracias!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Timer; 
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class jk extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    public jk() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("click");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(159, 159, 159)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 332, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

       String textoExtraido= jTextField1.getText();

        String txtConvertido = Morse(textoExtraido);
                msj(txtConvertido);
    }                                     



    public String Morse(String txtExtraido) {

                 //Extraigo el texto ingresado
        String txtConvertido = "0";                                         //Creo una cadena que siempre comenzara en apagado

        txtExtraido.toLowerCase();                                          //Convierto a minuscula

        char[] txtArray = txtExtraido.toCharArray();                        //Creo un arreglo que contiene todas las letras de la cadena

        for (int i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++) {                         //Recorro el arreglo  

            switch (txtArray[i]) {
                case 'a':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido + "10110";
                    break; //a-z
                case 'b':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"110101010";
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1101011010";
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1101010";
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"10";
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"101011010";
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"11011010";
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"10101010";
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1010";
                    break;
                case 'j':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"10110110110 ";
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"11010110";
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"101101010";
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"110110";
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"11010";
                    break;
                case 'ñ':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"11011010110110";
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"110110110";
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1011011010";
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"11011010110 ";
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1011010";
                    break;
                case 's':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"101010";
                    break;
                case 't':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"110";
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1010110";
                    break;
                case 'v':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"101010110";
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"10110110";
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1101010110";
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"11010110110";
                    break;
                case 'z':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"1101101010";
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"000";                                  //Espacio entre palabra
                default:
                    break;
            }

            txtConvertido=txtConvertido +"00000";                                        //Final de la oracion
        }
        return (txtConvertido);                                                   //Devuelve la cadena convertida en unos y ceros
    }


    public void msj(String txtC) {
        int j=0;
        char[] Mensaje;
        Mensaje = txtC.toCharArray();
        j= Mensaje.length;


                Timer timer = new Timer();
                TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

                public void run(){

                    decision(Mensaje, j);
                    if(Mensaje.length == j)
                    {
                        timer.cancel();
                    }

                   }
                };
                timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
                timer.cancel();
     }      








   public void decision(char [] Mensaje, int j) {

       if (Mensaje[j]  != '0') {
                jPanel1.setBackground(Color.white);


            } else {

                jPanel1.setBackground(Color.black);

            }

       j++;
   }





    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jk.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jk.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jk.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jk.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new jk().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar [java.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) en lugar de [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) para poder actualizar valores de componentes de swing utilizando el [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

En cuanto a la variable final, podrías poner la variable como una variable de instancia y no dentro del método

```
int j=0;
public void msj(String txtC) {
    j=0;
    char[] Mensaje;
    Mensaje = txtC.toCharArray();
    j= Mensaje.length;


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        public void run(){

            decision(Mensaje, j);
            if(Mensaje.length == j)
            {
                timer.cancel();
            }

           }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
        timer.cancel();
 }
```